# What facets have I missed for creating a 3 person guerilla dev team?

Tags: macos

Sorry for the Windows developers out there, this solution is for Macs only.

This set of applications accounts for: Usability Testing, Screen Capture (Video and Still), Version Control, Task Lists, Bug Tracking, a Developer IDE, a Web Server, A Blog, Shared Doc Editing on the Web, Team and individual Chat, Email, Databases and Continuous Integration. This does assume your team members provide their own machines, and one person has a spare old computer to be the Source Repository and Web Server. All for under $200 bucks.

**Usability**

[Silverback](http://silverbackapp.com/)

Licenses = 3 x $49.95

"Spontaneous, unobtrusive usability testing software for designers and developers."

**Source Control Server and Clients (multiple options)**

[Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) = Free

Subversion is an open source version control system.

[Versions](http://versionsapp.com/) (Currently in Beta) = Free

Versions provides a pleasant work with Subversion on your Mac.

[Diffly](http://lucidmac.com/products/diffly) = Free

"Diffly is a tool for exploring Subversion working copies. It shows all files with changes and, clicking on a file, shows a highlighted view of the changes for that file. When you are ready to commit Diffly makes it easy to select the files you want to check-in and assemble a useful commit message."

**Bug/Feature/Defect Tracking (multiple options)**

[Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/) = Free

Bugzilla is a "Defect Tracking System" or "Bug-Tracking System". Defect Tracking Systems allow individual or groups of developers to keep track of outstanding bugs in their product effectively. Most commercial defect-tracking software vendors charge enormous licensing fees.

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) = Free

Trac is an enhanced wiki and issue tracking system for software development projects.

**Database Server & Clients**

[MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/?rz=gdl#downloads) = Free

[CocoaMySQL](http://cocoamysql.sourceforge.net/) = Free

**Web Server**

[Apache](http://apache.org/) = Free

**Development and Build Tools**

[XCode](http://www.apple.com/macosx/features/300.html#xcode3) = Free

[CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) = Free

CruiseControl is a framework for a continuous build process. It includes, but is not limited to, plugins for email notification, Ant, and various source control tools. A web interface is provided to view the details of the current and previous builds.

**Collaboration Tools**

[Writeboard](http://www.writeboard.com/) = Free

[Ta-da List](http://www.tadalist.com/) = Free

[Campfire Chat](https://signup.37signals.com/campfire/free/signup/new) for 4 users = Free

[WordPress](http://wordpress.org/download/) = Free

"WordPress is a state-of-the-art publishing platform with a focus on aesthetics, web standards, and usability. WordPress is both free and priceless at the same time."

[Gmail](http://www.gmail.com/) = Free

"Gmail is a new kind of webmail, built on the idea that email can be more intuitive, efficient, and useful."

**Screen Capture (Video / Still)**

[Jing](http://www.jingproject.com/) = Free

"The concept of Jing is the always-ready program that instantly captures and shares images and video…from your computer to anywhere."

---

**Lots of great responses:**

TeamCity [Yo|||]

Skype [Eric DeLabar]

FogBugz [chakrit]

IChatAV and Screen Sharing (built-in to OS) [amrox]

Google Docs [amrox]

---

Comment: Interesting question! I wonder if there is a similar post regarding Windows development.

Comment: Windows dev use mostly the same stuff.

Comment: Seems odd the list starts with Usability, and it contains the only product that costs money, and Guerilla : Silverback intended pun?  A Silverback plug thinly disguised?

Comment: At the time of this message I was actually working for a company that makes a Windows UX product :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got most of it covered.

I always add space, time and money for 2 more things you might consider strange.

1. A machine set up just like the average user. No development or debugging tools installed. Make it look like someone just bought it from the Apple store. I do image switching but I've know people who swear by switching to an external boot drive.
2. Also include a 'free' lunch for a virgin. This is someone to come in and test your program that is NOT a developer and doesn't know squat about your software. You might have to do this more than once but don't ever use the same person again.

As an added note, make very sure the 'free' applications and web sites you use are truly free, not just free for personal use!

Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 1):

**Collaboration Tools**

[Skype](http://www.skype.com/) = Free - If you can't work face-to-face a tool like Skype can get you pretty close for no cost assuming everybody already has broadband.  The mac client works great and since most modern macs have a camera already you should be mostly set.

Comment: Communication being key in this environment, I like this. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah!  Skype is a great tool for distributed teams.

Answer (score 1):

Consider hudson as a CI server

Comment: yes - not sure when they forked/split  but this answer was made when I was using hudson

Answer (score 0):

Change CruiseControl for JetBrains' TeamCity. It's free for up to 20 users, and is more powerful and usable than CruiseControl.

It's easy to set up, and has some amazing features. Such as automatically sending off a build to be performed on any spare computer you may have sitting around in the office.

Comment: I have never used TeamCity, is it easy to set up?

Comment: more usable than CruiseControl... I second @Steve - less XML doc lookup,  think of CruiseControl with a spicy UI makeup.

Answer (score 0):

How do you do time tracking/scheduling/release planning?

Those that help you ship on time? ala FogBugz

Comment: I suppose you can put time tracking into Trac, but yeah FogBugz, or maybe 37signals' Basecamp.

Answer (score 0):

Trac and Subversion have a pretty nice integration that lets you link Trac tickets to SVN change sets and vice-versa (SVN change sets can actually move a Trac ticket to a new state).

Answer (score 0):

Some built-in Leopard tools that I find useful are iChat AV and Screen Sharing.

Also, Google Docs, especially spreadsheets and forms are nice (and free).

Answer (score 0):

- **Version control**: [svnX](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/development_tools/svnx.html) is a *free* GUI-based Subversion client.
- **RDBMS**: [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) is a *free* relational database with a track record stretching back a couple of *decades*.  It's [easily installed on OS X](http://developer.apple.com/internet/opensource/postgres.html).
- **IDE**: If (and possibly only if) you're coding Java, [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) is an unbeatable (and *free*) IDE for Java (and other platforms, though I'm not vouching for anything other than it's Java ability).
- **Screencasting**: [ScreenFlow](http://www.flip4mac.com/screenflow.htm) is outstanding at $US 99.